# Binding HeaderText to string in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm in the process of debugging some old code that contains .aspx files and c# files for the code behind. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to bind the text in 'HeaderText' for a TemplateField. (Note: Never worked with aspx before). Basically I have an array of strings in the code-behind and a few different TemplateFields in the .aspx files. I want to bind the HeaderText of those fields to the strings. I know for TextBoxes it would be

```
Text = '<%# bindingStuffHere %>
```

As an example, say I have a template field like below:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=""  >
```

And in the code behind I have:

```
String[] days = new String[5]
days[0] = "SAT"
```

I want to bind "SAT" to the HeaderText. The template is in a GridView.

Comment: `TemplateField ` inside what `Gridview`, `ListView` or which control? Show small but complete code.

Comment: GridView. I'm not sure I can post small code besides what I posted. It's thousands of lines long and has many errors. The guy who wrote it hard-coded many things so I'm trying to go through and fix a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind HeaderText in asp:TemplateField. Instead you can implement OnRowDataBound event and change the header text there.

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = days[i];
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you, I'll play around with that now!

Comment: Glad I could help. Just remember to mark this as the answer if this resolves your issue.